# On click submit a form the redirect to a URL is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have list of items,for each item i have one button. On clicking that button i am submitting the form. Inside `submit` function i am redirecting to a url.

HTML

```
<div style="float:left;margin-top:4px;" class="enroll_onload" data-content="localhost/action/event_calendar/manageonal&amp;event_id=40117&amp;group_guid=40129&amp;user_id=2&amp;course_id=12" data-id="40117" id="enroll_btn">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="enroll_to">
<span class="enroll_button">Enroll</span>
</a></div>

<form method="post" action="http://10.0.1.22/firstplanet/fpin/dev/learn/amfphp/services/data/rest/enrollCourseOnLoad" id="enroll40117">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="user_id"><input type="hidden" value="admin" name="name">
<input type="hidden" value="any@gmail.com" name="email">
<input type="hidden" value="administrator" name="username">
<input type="hidden" value="any.png" name="userImage"><input type="hidden" value="12" name="course_id">
</form>
```

So like this i have another `ten items with different values & id`.

SCRIPT

```
$('div.enroll_onload').live('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var form_id = $(this).next('#enroll'+id);
        var hrefTo = $(this).attr('data-content');
        $(form_id).submit(function() {
            alert('working');

            var formData = {
                    'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
                    'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
                    'user_id'           : $('input[name=user_id]').val(),
                    'username'          : $('input[name=username]').val(),
                    'userImage'         : $('input[name=userImage]').val(),
                    'course_id'         : $('input[name=course_id]').val()
                };
            $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                url         : '<?php echo $vars['url']?>learn/amfphp/services/data/rest/enrollCourseOnLoad',
                data        : formData,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data){
                        window.location.href = hrefTo;
                    } 
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

I am facing the problem when i submit the function its not submitting i debug the script after submit its not going to the function, means its executes up to `$(form_id).submit(function() {` then its skipping all the rest.

Any idea whats the problem ?

Comment: where's your submit button?

Comment: You just need to do `form_id.submit()` instead of `$(form_id).submit()`

Comment: did u tried  `e.preventDefault();`? and check this link [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121958/jquery-ajax-post-inside-a-form-prevent-form-submission-on-ajax-call)

Comment: Guys i found the answer ...Its just no need there to submit & ajax at one time except form validation...otherwise just do only ajax its enough..

Answer (score 0):

`$('div.enroll_onload').live` removed on jquery 1.9 and new version

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have any submit button so the workaround can be

```
$('div.enroll_onload').on('click',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var form_id = $(this).next('#enroll'+id);
        var hrefTo = $(this).attr('data-content');
        var submitInput = $("<input type='submit' />");
        form_id.append(submitInput);
        submitInput.trigger("click");

});

// take out this function from the click function have it separately in document on load
$("#enroll40117").on("submit",function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();


            var formData = {
                    'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
                    'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
                    'user_id'           : $('input[name=user_id]').val(),
                    'username'          : $('input[name=username]').val(),
                    'userImage'         : $('input[name=userImage]').val(),
                    'course_id'         : $('input[name=course_id]').val()
                };
 });
```

Comment: No i found the answer...i removed the form submit & done in ajax..TY