# Display a success message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I wanted to display a success message in the same modal a user input the information but am not getting the result I want

```js
$.ajax({
  url: form.attr('action'),
  type: form.attr('method'),
  data: formData,
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(html) {
    $("#createTakeoutBtn").button('reset');
    $("#TakeoutForm")[0].reset();
    $("html, body, div.modal, div.modal-content, div.modal-body").animate({
      scrollTop: '0'
    }, 100);

    $('#add-takeout-messages').html('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>' +
      '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> ' + 'Successfuly Saved' +
      '</div>');

    // remove the mesages
    $(".alert-success").delay(500).show(10, function() {
      $(this).delay(3000).hide(10, function() {
        $(this).remove();
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="add-takeout-messages"></div>
```

This is the result am getting right now

```
{
  "success": true,
  "messages": "Successfully Added"
}
```

[image]

Comment: try to alert(html.messges) in success method

Comment: You mean, you are getting object and you want to display only the `messages` value?

Comment: try append to add-takeout-messages

Comment: 'I am not getting the result I want' is not really useful information to help you solve this issue. What result do you get? What result do you actually want to have?

Comment: @Vishwa I did try that it gives me the same result

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, the result I want is to display the success message under the header of the modal but it displays a page with the response message on it

Comment: @ek145 attach a screenshot, we dont know what result you get and what you expect

Comment: did you try alert(html.messges);in success method?

Comment: yes  I did it is still the same

Comment: why don't just show / hide message html based on response.

Comment: So basically you want to display "successfully Added" instead of {"success": true,"messages": "Successfully Added"} ?

Comment: @PavanShetty yes but I want that message to be under the header of the modal the user entered the inputs on and not on different page

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you forget to concate html.messages

```
$('#add-takeout-messages').html('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>' +
      '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> ' + html.messages +
      '</div>');
```

Please use `data`/`response` insetead of `html` in success method to prevent confusion i.e

```
success: function(response) {
      $('#add-takeout-messages').html('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
      '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>' +
      '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> ' + response.messages +
      '</div>');
}
```

Comment: it is still the same

Answer (score 0):

The problem is hidden in the comments:

> the result I want is to display the success message under the header of the modal but it displays a page with the response message on it

You're trying to trigger this ajax request with a form submit button, but have forgotten to prevent the default action of the form -- so instead of the ajax request, the whole page is being refreshed with the script results.

To prevent this, you can use `event.preventDefault` or `return false` from the [form submit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121958/jquery-ajax-post-inside-a-form-prevent-form-submission-on-ajax-call):

```
// "form" variable defined earlier, as shown in your existing code
form.bind('submit', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({ .... })
}
```

...or use a button other than "submit" to trigger the AJAX request.

Answer (score -1):

I create two files a index.php file and another one called request.php, I dont know if you are using php or json or another back end lenguage, the important part is the structure of the json you get from your ajax and the ajax itself, I also run the ajax call on some custom button with a click event you can fire the ajax call wherever you want it will be the same, here is the code:

the php :

```
$array = [
  "status"=>"success",
  "messages"=>  [
    array('date' => "2019-04-11", 'msg'=>'Love you', 'from'=>'Annie' ),
    array('date' => "2019-04-10", 'msg'=>'Have a nice day', 'from'=>'Annie' )
  ]

];
echo json_encode($array);
```

or json:

```
{"status":"success","messages":[{"date":"2019-04-11","msg":"Love you","from":"Annie"},{"date":"2019-04-10","msg":"Have a nice day","from":"Annie"}]}
```

the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var formData = {id:"1",name:"stan",lastname:"chacon",color:"blue"};
  function _ajaxMessage(formData){
    return $.ajax({
      url: "request.php",
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json'
    })
  }

  $("#btnDisplayModal").on('click', function(){
    _ajaxMessage(formData)
    .done(function(response){
      $('#add-takeout-messages').empty();
      $.each(response.messages,function(index,value){
        console.log(index,value);
      $('#add-takeout-messages').append('<div class="alert alert-success">' +
    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>' +
    '<strong><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i></strong> From: '+ value.from + '<br>' +  ' msg: ' + value.msg +
    '</div>')
      })
      $("#myModal").modal();
    })
  })

})
```

> Note i use boostrap 4.

it displays:

[image: Modal]

Hope it helps =)