# Using Microsoft OWIN GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions, how can we add custom logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-signin

We are using the below in our ASP.NET MVC 3 web application to add Google sign in and it works well.

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions() {
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientId"],
    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientSecret"],
    CallbackPath = new PathString("/GoogleLoginCallback"),
});
```

However, my requirements are to *not* sign them in automatically, unless other requirements are met. How can I prevent this from automatically setting them as authenticated? I just need like an interceptor and a few lines of code to be ran to indicate if they should sign in or not.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using the standard `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google` [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) and boilerplate, you could use any of these ways

1. Use `ExternalLogin` (HttpPost) in the `AccountCountroller` and add your custom logic just before `return new ChallengeResult(...)`
2. Or you could implement that extra checks via an ajax request before submitting the form. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8122013/2091519) for an example

Comment: Not a bad idea, do my logic PRIOR to sending them out to google.